# Degraded health status when deploying spring boot application in Elastic Beanstalk in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy a sprint boot application using an executable jar file in Elastic Beanstalk. After creating the environment and uploading the jar file, the health status is shown as degraded and the application throws a 502 bad gateway error. I have made the server_port = 5000 in the spring boot application.

This is the error message shown in the log file:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Jun 22 06:53:48 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Jun 22 06:53:48 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
Jun 22 06:53:48 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
Jun 22 06:53:48 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
Jun 22 06:53:48 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/thiluxan/alpha_health_care/AlphaHealthCareApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
Jun 22 06:53:49 ip-172-31-2-238 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

In the elastic beanstalks, the java platform is set to Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.15.

Comment: It looks like you are compiling your JAR file locally with a newer version of Java (Java 11 specifically), before uploading it to Elastic Beanstalk. You need to stick with Java 8 locally if Corretto 8 is what you are using on AWS.

Comment: Wrong java version configured in aws